# Facebook - URL returned a bad HTTP response code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-status-code-404, response

For my website, www.mymoviematch.com, I cannot share any articles / pages on facebook due to facebook not scraping my site.

When I try the debugger, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mymoviematch.com%2Fpremiere%2F, it gives me "URL returned a bad HTTP response code", 404 error.

Meta tags and server response seem to be alright, so no idea what that might cause.
I have read many similar problems, but cant find fix for mine... Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook can't scrape meta data after I've moved Wordpress to new server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220600/facebook-cant-scrape-meta-data-after-ive-moved-wordpress-to-new-server)

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am currently experiencing the same problem and cannot find the correct answers anywhere. I can share links to my pages, but links to my posts return "not found"

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I have managed to fix my problem. The issue were the DNS records that were blocking the scraper. So if you have similar issue, check your DNS records. Thanks for help.

Comment: How can you check whether the DNS is blocking the scraper?

Comment: This does not fully solve the problem, how do you check? And what do you change?

Comment: Agree with the comments above.  No explanation as to what was actually done or how to fix the issue.

Comment: Nothing to do with DNS here since he is getting a http response from the server, In our case Fb was scraping a www version of our website which does not exist , when we set the correct og:url tag in header , it worked . Please see @Tobi answer

Answer (score 6):

The error is quite strange. The only thing that comes in my mind is that you apparantly use an incomplete url in the

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mymoviematch.com" />
```

tag. I think it should match the full URL.

Comment: Hi Tobi, thanks a lot for your answer. I had the complete url but did not work - that's why I tried to change things and put the homepage url instead, but without success... It seems like whatever I change in the meta-tags, does not matter. I always get the same error messages.

Comment: There are some bug reports for the FB platform currently with similar content. Maybe you check that as well.

Comment: That was it for me - the `og:url` was incorrect.. side note: I am constantly whispering to myself: "oh yeah, the original gangster URL!"

Comment: Thanks this worked for us , In our case the og:url tag was missing and FB was fetching an invalid url automatically. Setting the og:url tag in header to correct url fixed our issue

Comment: Thank you. This fixed our issue. It's just weird that the same wrong og url works fine on WhatsApp and Slack and even random wesbites that generates page previews but on Facebook it complains when it sees a wrong url. Guess Facebook are usually right.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem and solved it by changing my DNS settings. Facebook uses IP V6 so you need to specify correct IP V6 in your AAAA record (not only IP V4).

Answer (score 2):

I had a rule in my **apache mod security** in the way. Temporarily deactivating it helped me. An IPv6 record is not required. I have only IPv4 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs due to IPV6 address. Facebook by default use IPV6 address if available. My VPS has IPV6 enabled.

To Solve this problem you have to enable iPv6 in All Ningx config files for each virtual host (if many sites hosted) to listen Any IPv6 address at port 80.

This will solve the issue with Facebook opengraph.

Alternatively, you can completely disable IPV6 address to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of your server's `MOD SECURITY`. It block some patterns. try to add this line in your vhosts. (`yourdomain.com.ssl.conf`)

```
<Directory "/home/username/public_html">
        .......
        .......
        SecRuleRemoveById 958291
</Directory>
```

Make sure to check the `mod_security` logs and find the exact sec ID. In my case I added secID `958291`

Answer (score 0):

Facebook not only need OG header but also need Facebook Pages on header and check robots.txt whether you allow or not Facebook’s crawler  user-agent: facebookexternalhit

I had summarize here after our customer encountered issues with Facebook URLs, resulting in a bad HTTP response code (403) when attempting to share links on the Facebook platform.

https://sobiztrend.com/facebook-url-returned-a-bad-http-response-code/

Answer (score -1):

The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided.